# Django Rest Framework AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do simple tests on my newly created viewsets, by using the [APIClient](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient) class instead of [APIRequestFactory](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apirequestfactory), however, the view fails with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

It works fine if I use APIRequestFactory though, but I need APIClient since I am using [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

This is the context in which I am using the client:

```
api_client = APIClient()
reversed_url = reverse('showcase:ajax:publisher-dashboard', kwargs={'pk': 1})
client_token = cm.Client.objects.get(first_name='Cliente 1',
                                     last_name='Prueba Showcase').user.auth_token.key
api_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + client_token)

request = api_client.get(reversed_url, format='json')
response = views.PubViewSet.as_view({'get': 'dashboard'})(request, pk=1)
```

The results are the same without providing credentials and disabling TokenAuth in settings.py.

These are the contents of the Response object when using APIRequestFactory:

```
<Response status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">

_charset = {NoneType} None
_closable_objects = {list} <class 'list'>: []
_container = {list} <class 'list'>: [b'']
_content_type_for_repr = {str} ', "text/html; charset=utf-8"'
_handler_class = {NoneType} None
_headers = {dict} {'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')}
_is_rendered = {bool} False
_post_render_callbacks = {list} <class 'list'>: []
_reason_phrase = {NoneType} None
_request = {NoneType} None
charset = {str} 'utf-8'
closed = {bool} False
content = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/ariel/.local/pycharm-2017.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 197, in _getPyDictionary\n    attr = getattr(var, n)\n  File "/home/ariel/.virtualenvs/recrow-app/lib/python3.6/site-packag
content_type = {NoneType} None
context_data = {NoneType} None
cookies = {SimpleCookie} 
data = {dict} {'publisher': {'id': 1, 'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'name': 'TEST', 'official_name': 'TEST, S.A.', 'rfc': 'XAXXXXXXX000X', 'street': 'St.', 'number': '420', 'interior': '', 'neighborhood': '', 'zipcode': '', 'email': '', 'phone': '', 'image': '/rcro
exception = {bool} False
is_rendered = {bool} False
reason_phrase = {str} 'OK'
rendered_content = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/ariel/.local/pycharm-2017.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 197, in _getPyDictionary\n    attr = getattr(var, n)\n  File "/home/ariel/.virtualenvs/recrow-app/lib/python3.6/site-packag
rendering_attrs = {list} <class 'list'>: ['template_name', 'context_data', '_post_render_callbacks']
status_code = {int} 200
status_text = {str} 'OK'
streaming = {bool} False
template_name = {NoneType} None
using = {NoneType} None
```

And when APIClient is used:

```
<Response status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">

_charset = {NoneType} None
_closable_objects = {list} <class 'list'>: []
_container = {list} <class 'list'>: [b'']
_content_type_for_repr = {str} ', "text/html; charset=utf-8"'
_handler_class = {NoneType} None
_headers = {dict} {'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')}
_is_rendered = {bool} False
_post_render_callbacks = {list} <class 'list'>: []
_reason_phrase = {NoneType} None
_request = {NoneType} None
charset = {str} 'utf-8'
closed = {bool} False
content = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/ariel/.local/pycharm-2017.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 197, in _getPyDictionary\n    attr = getattr(var, n)\n  File "/home/ariel/.virtualenvs/recrow-app/lib/python3.6/site-packag
content_type = {NoneType} None
context_data = {NoneType} None
cookies = {SimpleCookie} 
data = {dict} {'publisher': {'id': 1, 'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'name': 'TEST', 'official_name': 'TEST, S.A.', 'rfc': 'XAXXXXXXX000X', 'street': 'St.', 'number': '420', 'interior': '', 'neighborhood': '', 'zipcode': '', 'email': '', 'phone': '', 'image': '/rcro
exception = {bool} False
is_rendered = {bool} False
reason_phrase = {str} 'OK'
rendered_content = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/ariel/.local/pycharm-2017.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 197, in _getPyDictionary\n    attr = getattr(var, n)\n  File "/home/ariel/.virtualenvs/recrow-app/lib/python3.6/site-packag
rendering_attrs = {list} <class 'list'>: ['template_name', 'context_data', '_post_render_callbacks']
status_code = {int} 200
status_text = {str} 'OK'
streaming = {bool} False
template_name = {NoneType} None
using = {NoneType} None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have error in this lines of code:

```
request = api_client.get(reversed_url, format='json')
response = views.PubViewSet.as_view({'get': 'dashboard'})(request, pk=1)
```

`api_client.get` already return HTTPResponse, so you dont need to pass it to VewSet as request. Instead of it try this:

```
response = api_client.get(reversed_url)
assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: You are completely right, I thought it was a drop in replacement for APIRequestFactory but it actually generates a complete get request to the specified URL. I had to take a second look to [Django's original Client class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) to verify this. Thank you for clarifying this.